# Test framework quit unexpectedly: cat: /tmp/tmp.z5uNpMUXj6: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, cmake, clion

I've got a problem using CLion 2020.1.2. I submitted a [question](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009387740--cat-tmp-tmp-VEwej1syj9-No-such-file-or-directory-error-in-clion-debugger-) to the help forum a few days ago but not getting a response, so I'm reposting the question here.

Basically the issue is that my test program runs fine outside of debugger mode - I'm using googletest - but as soon as I set a breakpoint and try to run the debugger the `test framework quit unexpectedly` with the following message:

```
Testing started at 12:50 ...
D:\libOmexMeta\cmake-build-release-wsl-ubuntu1804-gcc101\bin\OmexMetaTests --gtest_color=no
cat: /tmp/tmp.zA2hjQPSYh: No such file or directory
cat: /tmp/tmp.65NNrNx20t: No such file or directory
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm basically stumped with this one so I've been developing without a debugger, which is less than ideal. I thought it might have something to do with `Release` Vs `Debug` flags so I tried again with :

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O0")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-O0")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O0")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O0")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-O0")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-O0")
```

in my cmake script - which does nothing, it seems. Any idea what is going on here?

I also tried using msvc compilers and the debugger just skips over break points.

I forgot to mention that I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 from WSL.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I can't, same behaviour in a clean hello world project. I'm starting to wonder if this is a WSL problem

Comment: I don't know what the problem was but after a painful reinstalling of WSL along with all dependencies I was able to use the debugger again.

Comment: You've got both a windows path and a unix path in your error message.  I don't have a windows machine to play with, but this screams to me that something is messy with your WSL setup.  See if you can build/run entirely within your linux environment.